# numpy.concatenate error: Zero dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Tags: python, numpy

Code:

```
print("****SHAPE***",input_feature_train.shape,target_feature_train_df_reshaped.shape)
train_arr = np.concatenate([input_feature_train,target_feature_train_df_reshaped],axis=1)
```

Error Message:

```
****SHAPE*** (14599, 234) (14599, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 87, in initiate_data_transformation
    train_arr = np.concatenate([input_feature_train,target_feature_train_df_reshaped],axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in concatenate
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Comment: one of the concatenate arrays is actually a scalar.  Check them!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Can you give more information about the contents and types of your arrays?

Comment: I can't reproduce, please include a [mcve], tried `print(np.concatenate([np.zeros((2, 2)), np.zeros((2, 1))], axis=1))`